# Take specific amount of rows from table dependent on column value

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for guidance on how to programmatically limit the number of rows in a `DataTable`, depending on a specific column value.

Similar to how `take(n)` would allow me to get a specific number of rows:

```
// Returns first 10 rows
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(10).CopyToDataTable();
```

---

Say I had a `DataTable` with 4 rows

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               Col1                |    Col2    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| FRED                              |            |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| BILL                              |            |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| BILL                              |            |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| BOB                               |            |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

With this scenario `take(2)` would return 2 rows, but I want similiar functionality to return 3 as Col1's value is the same in row 2 and 3.

Would this be fastest with a loop:

```
var count = 0;

for(int i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // add to new DataTable

    if(i > 0 && Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Col1"]) != Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i-1]["Col1"]))
    {
        // check next row
        count++;
        if (count == 10) break;
    }
}
```

or is there another easier solution?

**I'm looking for the distinct values limited to a specific number, but to also get all the duplicates.**

Comment: Your requirement does not really make sense. Do you maybe want 3 rows because there is three distinct values?

Comment: So did I understand correctly: you want two Col1 values and if there are multiple rows with the same value (BILL here) then all those need to be retrieved? Probably grouping and ungrouping might work

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That is correct, I tried to explain the best I could, but it's a strange one. There will be a limit on the distinct values, which is where I was going with take(), but there can be many more rows in the resulting DataTable due to duplicate Col1

Comment: @nvoigt In the example I want 2 distinct rows, but a result of 3 rows, so including the duplicates. Sorry for not explaining this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in a comment: "I want the distinct values limited to a specific number, but get all the duplicates.". So you only need to take rows until the distinct number of values taken is larger than your limit. For that purpose, a hashset is the easiest option, it will automatically have each distinct value only once, even when you add them multiple times.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();
var limit = 2;

var resultingRows = sequence.TakeWhile(row => { set.Add(row[col]); return set.Count <= limit; });
```

Make sure sequence is materialized and ordered by that column.

Comment: Wouldn't the first step require "sequence" to have no duplicates in the first X?

Comment: That would get you "FRED, BILL, BOB". You want "FRED, BILL, BILL" right?

Comment: The edit option is just what I'm looking for, thank you. If you have time could you provide a little explanation, if not I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I got it right, you want to get a list of rows excluding duplicates, where two rows are considered equal if they have the same value in `Col1`, right?

In that case, you might define an [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) for your rows:

```
class RowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return x["Col1"] == y["Col1"];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return obj["Col1"].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

...and then get the "unique" rows by using LINQ's `Distinct`:

```
var uniqueRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Distinct(new RowComparer())
```

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite. I want the distinct values limited to a specific number, but get all the duplicates.